# Jquery does not work for the first click on the enter key in an html input

Tags: html, jquery

I want when a user type something in an input, after pressing enter key, the jquery do something. I am using the following code, but there is a problem on the first time pressing enter key. Actually it does not work. What's the problem and how to fix it?

```js
$('.tag-input').on('change' , (e) =>{
     $(this).on("keydown", event=> {
        if(event.which == 13 && $('.tag-input').val().length>0)
           alert($('.tag-input').val());
     });
});
```

```css
.tag-input{
  width:80%;
 }
```

```html
<div >
    <input class="tag-input" placeholder="Type something then press 'Enter' key." />
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: $('.tag-input').on("keydown", event=> {
        if(event.which == 13 && $('.tag-input').val().length>0)
           alert($('.tag-input').val());
     }); use this. You are using change and keydown two event  on one element

Answer (score 3):

The issue is because you've nested the `keydown` event handler within the `change` event. Nesting event handlers is rarely a good thing to do. Use a single `keydown` event handler:

```js
$('.tag-input').on('keydown', e => {
  const $input = $(e.target);
  if (e.which == 13 && $input.val().trim().length > 0)
    console.log($input.val());
});
```

```css
.tag-input {
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input class="tag-input" placeholder="Type something then press 'Enter' key." />
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

That being said, a better approach entirely would be to wrap your `input` in a `form` element and put the `required` attribute on it. That way you don't need any JS at all:

```css
.tag-input {
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form action="/search">
    <input class="tag-input" required placeholder="Type something then press 'Enter' key." />  
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I want do some back ends. So required is not OK for me.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.tag-input').bind('keyup',function() {            
        alert(this.value);
});
```

```css
.tag-input{
  width:80%;
 }
```

```html
<div >
    <input class="tag-input" placeholder="Type something then press 'Enter' key." />
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```